# Webhooks or something else?

Tags: node.js, api, subscription

I have REST-API over which users can request data from my DB. Now I would like to implement a user-subscription so a user can subscribe to a topic and gets notified in realtime, when some topic is updated in the DB.

So my question is, how would be the best way to implement it? I think about subscription via

- webhooks (a client simply sends a webhook-url in his subscription-url, to which a request is beeing made from my server)
- websockets (a client subscribes via websockets and the server sends a message to the client when needed)

Please correct me if I am wrong, but would this be enough? Could/should I implement something else? How would you do it?

Comment: A webhook will only work for clients *that are also servers*, right? If this is intended for consumption by general internet users, a websocket would be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, I think about implementing both, so normal internet-users can subscribe via websockets and server-based solution can subscribe via webhook.. or does it make sense ONLY to rely on webhooks?

Comment: If you only rely on webhooks, normal internet users won't be able to see updates in realtime. Depends on your intended audience.

Comment: Audience would be mixed, normal humans with their browsers which subscribe via webhook and server-sideded-apps which update their storages/etc.  Why sould normal internet users be able to recieve updated with webhooks?

Comment: They won't - which is why I said a websocket would be a better choice for them

Comment: Sorry I meant "Why should normal internet users NOT be able..? " .. i mean.. this is what websockets were meant for(?). Also I dont understand your last comment `They won't - which is why I said a websocket would be a better choice for them` .. you sure mean it the other way, right? webhooks make no sense to normal internet users, because they would need DynDNS and a local webserver which recieves the messages..  with websockets, a client-computer from a normal human beeing can simply send a subscription-msg and can recieve randomly messages from the server as long as the connection exists.

Comment: With webhooks, only a client computer which is also a server set up to receive HTTP requests can accept messages. You should use websockets for normal internet users to receive the messages.